# Preciso saber como eu uso um .text como banco de dados; apenas preciso que mostre os dados contidos no mesmo

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, android-studio

Meu aplicativo é um manual que quando o usuário clicar no item no listView apareça as descrições contidas de cada item, junto com uma foto.
Outra coisa como se colocaria os dados do .text em um ListView.
Essa é a minha duvida.

Comment: Olá Paulo Cesar. Bem, para o seu problema, acessar os dados de um arquivo .txt não é a solução, aliás, nunca guarde dados em arquivos .txt . O problema com eles é que vc tem que lidar com abertura e fechamento correto de arquivos, criar um algoritmo eficiente de acesso aos itens, etc. Ou seja, dá trabalho demais! Por isso, o ideal é você utilizar o banco de dados SQLite, pois ele é próprio para o Android , que já tem recursos próprios para realizar consultas, persistência, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá!
Vou lhe mostrar como carregar um .txt da pasta Assets: 
crie um arquivo chamado `dados.txt` dentro da pasta assets
Ele vai possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
item 1;descrição um;image1.png
item 2;descrição dois;image2.png
```

Para Carregar este arquivo use o seguinte código:

```
 /**
 * Carrega um arquivo txt e transforma as linhas em Objeto.
 */
private void load(){
      try {
         final InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("dados.txt");
         final InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream); 
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader); 
            final List<Item> itens = new ArrayList<MainActivity.Item>(0);
            String line = "";
                while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null){
                    String[] values = line.split(";");
                    final Item item = new Item(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
                    itens.add(item);
                }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 /** 
 * Representa o objeto que será exibido
 */
public static class Item {
     public Item(final String title, final String description, final String image) {
         this.title = title;
         this.description = description;
         this.image = image;
    }
     public String title;
     public String description;
     public String image;
 }
```

Espero ter ajudado!
Saudações!

Comment: Lembrando que também existem outros modelos para salvar estes dados, o demonstrado é o famoso CSV, mas também pode ser ser utilizado TSV que seria com separação por tab.
Ou ainda, um .txt que grave o conteúdo com tags XML ou ainda um JSON.